# TypeScript namespace could not be found

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing some piece of code in typescript. The code itself is a angular 2 app but the question is about typescript itself. I have some files containing my models like the one bellow:

```
module Models { 
    export class Customer { 
        public Id: number;
        public Name: string;
        public Orders: Order[];
        public CustomerPhones: CustomerPhone[];
    }
}
```

and some api client services like this one:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
module Api { 
    @Injectable()
    export class RestaurantMenuApiController {
        constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {
        } 

        public getAllMenus = ( context:any, fieldNameToFill: string, beforeFieldFilling:(data:Models.RestaurantMenu[])=>void, afterFieldFilling:(data:Models.RestaurantMenu[])=>void, failureHandler:()=>void, errorHandler:(error:any)=>void) => {
            var promise = this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/RestaurantMenuApi/getAllMenus');
            promise.subscribe(result => {
                if (result.ok) {
                    var data = <Models.RestaurantMenu[]>result.json();

                    if (beforeFieldFilling) {
                        beforeFieldFilling(data);
                    }

                    if(fieldNameToFill && fieldNameToFill != '')
                        context[fieldNameToFill] = data;

                    if (afterFieldFilling) {
                        afterFieldFilling(data);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    failureHandler();
                }
            }, error => {
                console.error("api call error: ",error);
                errorHandler(error);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

After these, when I use them in some other files, the expression `Api.RestaurantMenuApiController` says can not find namespace Api, while the code `Models.Customer` works just fine.

Where is my fault? I use both of them without import as unexported namespaces could not be imported.

Comment: By using a top level `export` _or_ `import` declaration declaration, you make a file a module. `namespace`s do not merge across module boundaries.

Comment: Angular basically requires a module aware toolchain anyway so why try to use `namespaces`? Also, call them what they are `module Api` -> `namespace Api` the latter is long deprecated.

Comment: @AluanHaddad The question is what makes difference between these two namespaces. You mean the imports at the first of the file makes the problem???

Comment: Yes, it means that they are _modules_. That also means they need to be `import`ed and that they should expose their api through `export`s

Comment: wow. @AluanHaddad, you are completely right. I moved the imports inside namespace and now `Api` is visible. Thanks. please post your answer.

Comment: Well, you are most welcome, but you may have missed the broader point. Nesting imports like that is actually invalid syntax and TypeScript should error on it. If it doesn't your loader/bundler will. You need to reduce nesting, not maintain or increase it. Write you app using ES Modules. Since you are using Angular, you already have all of the accreted complexity associated with a modular toolchain and you don't gain anything by avoiding it in your own code. Quite the contrary, you miss out on many benefits.

Comment: Yes you are right. I think posting whole these notes as an answer will help the futures.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad that you have found my remarks helpful. I will compose an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

> After these, when I use them in some other files, the expression Api.RestaurantMenuApiController says can not find namespace Api, while the code Models.Customer works just fine.

Your file with `Models` is global, whereas the file with `Api` is a module because of the `import` statements.

## Fix

Don't use globals.

## More

- [If you don't know what module vs. global means](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/modules.html).

Comment: Follow what "that TypeScript guy" said. :)